# Django Compressor to work with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, django, typescript, django-compressor

I want [Django Compressor](http://django_compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings/#django.conf.settings.COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS) to work with Microsoft new language [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org).

I downloaded the compiler `tsc` and it works fine.

When trying to use it with Django Compressor this way:

```
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/less', 'lessc {infile} {outfile}'),
    ('text/typescript', 'tsc {infile} {outfile}'),
    )
```

and

```
{% compress js %}
        <script type="text/typescript" charset="utf-8">
            var x=3;
            function greeter(person: string) {
            return "Hello, " + person;
            }

            var user = "Jane User";
        </script>
{% endcompress %}
```

the output is an empty JS script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I guess it is because the tsc program does not have the option to write the code to a predefined file.

Does someone have an idea?

(As said, the tsc works as well as django compressor for LESS..)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tsc file1.ts file2.ts` compiles file1.ts and file2.ts into file1.js and file2.js, respectively.

```
> tsc.exe
Syntax:   tsc [options] [file ..]

Examples: tsc hello.ts
      tsc --out foo.js foo.ts
      tsc @args.txt
```

Seems like you want to run `tsc {infile} --out {outfile}`

Comment: It works as you said, problem now is the if the tsc shows warnings (which is sometimes ok) the django-compressor treats this as errors and the page gets 500 FilterError because of the tsc warnings..any idea?

Comment: Maybe you should just suppress tsc.exe output by appending `>nul 2>&1`